# How to change the AudioClip of an AudioSource from script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I'm trying to do is changing the AudioClip to be played from a script on the AudioSource GameObject depending on the text of an button (difficulty of the game) when the it's pressed.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AudioEffects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip easyMusic;
    public AudioClip hardMusic;

    public AudioSource audioSource;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text difficultyButtonText;

    public void ChangeMusic()
    {
        var difficultyText = difficultyButtonText.text;
        var audioClip = audioSource.clip;
        
        if (difficultyText == "Easy")
        {
            audioClip = easyMusic;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
        else if (difficultyText == "Hard")
        {
            audioClip = hardMusic;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Searched within the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-clip.html), but nothing useful for the project. Within StackOverFlow found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38144935/12782411), but there's no better way of doing it?

Comment: It should rather be `audioSource.clip= easyMusic;` no need to store the reference in `audioClip` locally and then never use it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have never actually changed the value in the `audioSource` component. Just returning `clip` doesn't give you a reference to the property, it returns the value of `clip`. In your case you are creating a variable `audioClip` with the value of whatever `audioSource.clip` is at that time. From then on you just change the value in your variable, not your AudioSource component.

To solve it: You could either remove the `audioClip` variable all together and just assign `audioSource.clip` directly or set `audioSource.clip` at the end of your code to `audioClip`.

Comment: Thanks! Was thinking exactly what you wrote. The problem was that the button never called the `ChangeMusic()` function. Eventually I would've stumbled upon that error aswell. Again, thank you!